# Applescript to make the next tab the current document in Photoshop

Tags: applescript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm nearing the end of finishing an application that uses Google Vision to identify articles of clothing, and automatically crop to the article in Photoshop.

The first script I have goes through all of the open images and grabs their dimensions and file paths. Those are then passed to my application to do the rest of the magic.

I ran into an issue where it just kept cropping the same image over and over again. After a bit of debugging I realized that this is due to the fact that it will only crop the image that is "active" in photoshop.

So, I'm faced with the task of needing to call another script that sets the next tab as the active document in PS before hitting the crop function.

I was hoping for something easy like:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop 2020"
    set currentDocs to documents
    set currentDoc to next item of currentDocs
end tell
```

Well, that doesn't work...

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop 2020"
    set currentDocs to documents
    --  set myList to {}
    repeat with n from 1 to count of currentDocs
        set currentDoc to item (n + 1) of currentDocs
    end repeat
end tell
```

This works, but errors after the last tab because it goes out of bounds. (not sure how to stop that?) And the fact that it's in a loop doesn't help either. I just need a simple script that sets the currentDoc to the NEXT open image. Then I Can crop, move to the next image, crop, etc.
But it also needs to know the last tab so it doesn't go back through the images.

Comment: Use the [`repeat with loopVariable (in list)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-128481) syntax instead and set `current document` in each turn of the loop - as per [this example](https://paste.ee/p/Tmd3q)

Comment: Thanks @RobC. I did end up figuring it out. 
And I can't mark this as the answer because it was a comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the [`repeat with loopVariable (in list)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-128481) syntax instead.
2. Then set `current document` in each turn of the loop.

For example, the following loops over all open documents and crops them to 100 x 100 pixels:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop 2020"
  repeat with doc in documents as list
    set current document to doc
    crop doc bounds {0, 0, 100, 100}
  end repeat
end tell
```